# Setting commission for employees based on position

Tags: sql, oracle

I just started to learn some sql and I am using oracle database 11g. The question I have is that I have a staff table where I am trying to update the commission for each staff based on the position of the staff. I wanted to update the commission for regular employees to be 0.04(4%) and 0.05(5%) for managers.

Is there a way to do this all in one statement?

The way I did it was that I just updated all the staff commission by :

```
UPDATE staff SET commission = 0.04;
```

then I did another update statement to update just the manger

```
UPDATE staff SET commission = 0.05 WHERE position = 'Manager';
```

I was thinking something along the lines of this however this wouldnt work lol.

```
UPDATE staff SET commission = 0.04 WHERE NOT position = 'Manager' AND SET commission = 0.05
WHERE position = 'Manager';
```

Thanks for your help! much appreciated!

Comment: You can indent text by 4 spaces to have it formatted as code. Also add en empty line between code and other text.

Comment: OK thanks for the tips! Will do from now on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a `CASE` expression here:

```
UPDATE staff
SET commission = CASE WHEN position = 'Manager'
                      THEN 0.05
                      ELSE 0.04 END;
```

This assumes that you really want to do a blanket assignment to every non manager with a commission of 0.04.

Comment: got about 9 more mins till i can! Will do

Answer (score 1):

More flexible approach is to have a positions table containing position-dependent data.

```
CREATE TABLE position
(
    PositionID NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
    Position NVARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
    Commission NUMBER(8, 4) NOT NULL
);
```

Each staff member would then reference a position through a column

```
PositionID NUMBER(10) NOT NULL
```

Then you would only have to update the commission in the positions table

```
UPDATE position SET Commission = 0.05 WHERE Position = 'Manager';
```

This allows you to differentiate between more than two positions easily.

Also see: [Oracle / PLSQL: Foreign Keys](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/foreign_keys/foreign_keys.php).

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle decode is the handy short way:

```
 UPDATE staff
 SET commission = DECODE(position, 'Manager', 0.05, 0.04);
```